# LOAD CSV and Commits: Conditional (FOREACH/CASE) Execution Behaving Oddly

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm using Neo4j version 3.1, running what I thought would be a quite straightforward import, but have run into very significant problems. I'm importing data about pubs (for non-UK users, public houses - places where you have a pint and relax!). A `(pl:PubListing)` has been commented on by a `(u:BiteUser)`, creating a `(bc:BiteComment)`. I've got two CSV files, and have already imported the `(pl:PubListing)` nodes, so am trying to import the comments linked to each pub (on `pl.source_pub_id`) and to each user (on `u.username`). Importantly, I'd like to add them both as a simple relationship, and as what - for want of a better word - I term a chain.

In this way, the last two comments a user made (`bc1` being the most recent, and `bc2` the most recent but one) are linked to the user thus:

For the first comment:

`(u:BiteUser)-[:USER_PREVIOUS_COMMENT]->(bc1), (u)-[:USER_MADE_COMMENT]->(bc1)`

and the second:

`(u)-[:USER_MADE_COMMENT]->(bc2), (bc1)-[:USER_PREVIOUS_COMMENT]->(bc2)`

So far, so normal (bread and butter in a web app, where a comment might be something like a login event, password change, post, etc.). However, this isn't all happening in one neat transaction, rather when loading via CSV. My query is below.

*N.B. - a pre-processing script sorts the data so that all comments are in chronological order: the oldest comments come first, hence why there is no logic to position the comment in the correct place in the chain.*

*N.B. II - I'm using `MERGE` over create in several places here because of an expectation the query may be run more than once as new data becomes available or as those following up on this project (it's a talk) try to re-import data after technical difficulties. It's not a production script by any stretch of the imagination, and query optimization here is not top of my list of priorities.*

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///output-comments-0031.csv' AS line
// find the pub it refers to
MATCH (pl:PubListing) WHERE pl.source_pub_id = toInteger(line.source_pub_id)
MERGE (u:BiteUser {username: line.username })
// ensure the comment node is created
MERGE (bc:BiteComment { source_comment_id: toInteger(line.source_comment_id) })
SET
  // be flexible on scraped input
  bc += line,
  // indices should be integers, though
  bc.source_pub_id = toInteger(line.source_pub_id),
  bc.source_comment_id = toInteger(line.source_comment_id),
  bc.created_timestamp = toInteger(line.created_timestamp)
// link the comment to the user and pub directly
MERGE (u)-[:USER_MADE_COMMENT]->(bc)
MERGE (bc)-[:COMMENT_ABOUT_PUT]->(pl)
// and in a chain
// - this section will be repeated to link the comment to the 
// pub, in a chain. I've only included the user example 
// to isolate the problem for SO
WITH u, pl, bc
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[r:USER_PREVIOUS_COMMENT]->(lc:BiteComment)
WHERE lc <> bc
WITH u, bc, pl, r, CASE WHEN r IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END AS upc, lc
FOREACH (i IN upc |
  DELETE r
  CREATE (bc)-[:USER_PREVIOUS_COMMENT]->(lc)
)
// pre-processing means we know this is the most recent comment
// that the graph has seen yet
MERGE (u)-[:USER_PREVIOUS_COMMENT]->(bc)
```

The problem is that at present it creates both relationships for every comment. However, I when change the start of the query and add the following line after the `LOAD CSV` line,  and so load it one comment per transaction, it works as expected.

`WITH line SKIP 0 LIMIT 1`

and then,

`WITH line SKIP 1 LIMIT 1`

and then...

`WITH line SKIP 2 LIMIT 1`

... you get the idea.

My question is this. **Why is this happening during CSV import, and how can I stop it without running the import as individual transactions?**

Comment: One try: change the case when to: `CASE WHEN COUNT(r) = 1 then [1] else [] (...)`.

Comment: Maybe something related to all data being committed at the end of a single transaction..? And if you put USING `PERIODIC COMMIT 1` in the beginning of the script?

Comment: This should not be the best solution but can solve your problem and save your time for now. :)

Comment: Thanks, Bruno. I just tested the different condition and the result was the same (had tried several iterations of `IS NULL`, `size` and `COLLECT()` etc., but to no avail. Unfortunately the result is the same.

Comment: Also tried `USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1` as a stop-gap (although it's never clear what the units are here - are they db "hits"? IIRC, that is in itself an arbitrary unit). Either way, it didn't work. The only way I can make this query work in my graph at the moment is to run it as individual transactions.

Comment: Should add - that's not an immediate problem since I have a high performance machine so can do the million or so queries needed very quickly before my talk, I'd just like the undergraduates looking at it to be able to follow along too... and to know what's going on with this query!

Comment: To clarify: all comments (bc) are having two `:USER_PREVIOUS_COMMENT` relationships. One to a user and other to another comment, right?

Comment: No, each `(bc:BiteComment)` node will be related to one `(u:BiteUser)` node thus: `(u)-[:USER_MADE_COMMENT]->(bc)`. Every comment, apart from the first a user ever made, will be connected to another comment thus: `(bc1-[:USER_PREVIOUS_COMMENT]->(bc2)` (where `bc1` was the later comment), and the most recent comment a user made will be connected to the user thus: `(u)-[:USER_PREVIOUS_COMMENT]->(bc1)`

Comment: The intention (in this limited example - it's different with pubs) is to make it easy to query for: a) comments made by a user, and b), the most recent **n** comments made by a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to remember that Cypher queries do not process iteratively per row. Rather, they process all rows simultaneously and the iteration is per operation on all rows.

So you first MATCH to all rows, then you MERGE (second operation after your LOAD CSV) for all rows, etc.

Your CSV import seems to be going off of the (incorrect) assumption that rows are processed iteratively, so you have some kind of dependency on previously processed rows which will not work.

I'd advise you to fix your CSV to remove dependencies on previous row processing.

Either you'll need to do a COLLECT() of comments, then take the last two entries (something like `WITH collectedComments[-2..] as lastTwo`, then alias each node and create the relevant relationships), or you'll need to add timestamps or some other means of ordering, then perform a post-import query to grab the two latest comments and order them.

Comment: Aye, thanks! Your first three paragraphs have clarified the issue and I think I now know how to solve this, since execution is not iterative by line, I can either use a pre-processing script or (more likely), cypher footwork using `UNWIND` clauses on each node that should have a chain.

Comment: I'll solve this when I get in tomorrow - thanks again for the help, this had flummoxed me for hours.

Comment: Glad to help, we'll be happy to assist if you run into any further issues working on your fix.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to post the solution tomorrow, and be in touch if I need any help. I guess this illustrates the nuances of the differences between cypher and neo4j.